# embedded iframe element not working with youtube iframe api

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

Here's the jsfiddle for this project: http://jsfiddle.net/frankzfaz/bweH4/13/

The iframe elements I want to use are loaded into the html via javascript when a button is pushed:

```
document.getElementById('iframeload').innerHTML = '<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + metalMusicVid[indexVid].youTubeId + '?enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&showinfo=0&controls=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

As you can see, "metalMusicVid[indexVid].youTubeId" pulls youtube video IDs from a js array. This is how I want it to work.

I want this to work with the youtube api event listeners. As seen here:

```
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // youtube player api stuff
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    var player = document.getElementById("ytplayer");
    player.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
    player.addEventListener("onError", "onPlayerError");

                    // get current time and display it.
                      setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('vidTime').innerHTML = "Current: " + pad(Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime() / 60)) + ":" + pad(Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime() % 60))}, 1000);
                      // pads number with extra zeros, looking more like a real digital clock
                          function pad(val) {
                              var valString = val + "";
                              if (valString.length < 2) {
                                  return "0" + valString;
                              } else {
                                  return valString;
                              }
                          }
  }


function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    //console.log("New state " + newState); 
if(newState === 0){alert('the youtube api is working')}
if(newState === -1){alert('the youtube api is working')}
}

function onPlayerError(errorCode) {
  console.log("New ERROR " + errorCode);
}
```

This worked with object embeds, but I want to use iframes so it works better with ipads and mobile devices. And no, I don't want to load the iframes from the api itself as seen in the google documentation, because each video-id is loaded from a javscript array.

All I need is for these event listeners to pick up the new iframe from it's element id.

URL: http://jsfiddle.net/frankzfaz/bweH4/13/

Answer (score 0):

When using the iframe API. you don't have to have the YT.Player constructor generate the API ... if instead you pass, as an argument, either the ID of an existing iframe or a reference to an existing DOM element (and in either case omit the 'videoId' parameter) then the player object will be initialized with your existing iframe and set all your bindings. So instead of this:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
   var player = document.getElementById("ytplayer");
   player.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
   player.addEventListener("onError", "onPlayerError");
   // ... etc etc etc
```

You'd want something like this:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() { // called automatically when the iframe API loads.
  var player = new YT.Player(playerId, { // passing the reference to the DOM element of your existing iframe
    events: {
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
      'onError': onPlayerError
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried this, no luck. Probably because the iframe doesn't load when the page loads, it loads only when a function is activated (via an html button). Do I replace "playerId" with the iframe id? Because I tried that, no luck.

Comment: playerId can either be the DOM element itself (i.e. an object you create with document.getElementById) or can just be the ID attribute of the iframe as you suggest. However, you're correct that if the iframe itself doesn't load until a different function is activated, then this code wouldn't work (as it runs as soon as the code library is injected). What you'll want to do, then, is move the code that creates the YT.Player object to whatever function the HTML button triggers -- and just ensure that the iframe is fully loaded before it runs.

Comment: I tried putting function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){etc...} inside the function, after the iframe. Doesn't work either. Why is this not working? Should I use a setTimeout function to force onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() to load after the iframe is place by the function?

Comment: No, you won't want to put the whole function in there ... just put the logic (i.e. create the YT.Player object after you're sure the iframe exists). If the whole function is in there, it'll never get called. In fact, you could even try reversing the order ... putting the function that creates the iframe within the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function. If you want to create a fiddle with your whole code I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Okay, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frankzfaz/bweH4/13/ This is the old code with the object embed, but the iframe embed code is in there, commented out. Do your magic :)